# Filter data from WFS request in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wfs

In the past I have used OpenLayers in order to make WFS requests to geoserver and show features on a map. I have also used WFS rules in order to filter the data based on specific values. 
Now I am using Leaflet and I wonder whats the way to do something similar. Obviously Leaflet doesn't support many of the functionalities OpenLayers has but is there a way to show filtered features on the map?
Should I just bring the whole json through ajax jquery and then get the data I want from the jquery and show them?
Would it be an appropriate way?

Comment: Did you look at the [Leaflet-WFST](https://github.com/Flexberry/Leaflet-WFST) plugin?